# Why does the text in the span tags not center?

Tags: html, css

I am not exactly sure why the text does not center in the title class span.

```
<div id="vid_display">
 <span class="title">SampleText</span></br>
 <span class="desc">Sample Desc</span>
</div>
```

Stylesheet

```
#vid_display {
height: 500px;
width: 700px;
box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888;
}

.title {
font-family: cursive;
font-size: 20px;
font-style: bold;
text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`text-align` doesn't have any effect on inline elements like span tags. You need to apply your text-alignment onto the parent element that is `display:block;` like the `<div>` or `<p>` that is wrapping the span.

You might be better off with something like this:

**HTML**

```
<div id="vid_display">
 <p class="title">SampleText</p>
 <p class="desc">Sample Desc</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.title { text-align: center; }
```

**Update:** Here is a working sample: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jEnys

Answer (score 1):

is an inline element and not a block. Use div instead:

```
<div id="vid_display">
  <div class="title">SampleText</div><br>
  <span class="desc">Sample Desc</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
 <div class="title">SampleText</div></br>
```

The `<span>` tag is used to group inline-elements in a document.
The `<span>` tag provides no visual change by itself.
`<span>` defaults to being `display:inline;` whereas `<div>` defaults to being `display:block;`.